# Connecting Php Script on Local Host to online sql Server database

Tags: php, sql-server

I have connected php with sql server when both these lie on my local computer.

But I need to connect with an SQL Server Web Database when my PHP script is running on local computer.

I have added the extensions `php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll` and `php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll` in my PHP extensions.

For connection with SQL Server on my localhost I also needed a SQL Server Native Client Driver which I have already installed but does this also have to do anything with my connection to SQL Server web database?

When I run the PHP Script the script takes some time to execute and sometimes gives an error :

> SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]TCP
>   Provider: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did
>   not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond. 1

My connection script is

```
    $serverName = "***.db.*****.********.com";
    try{
      $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$serverName;Database=*****",   "***UserName***", "***PWD***");
      $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    }
    catch(Exception $e){ 
      die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) ); 
    }
```

Comment: are you sure that database server is reachable from the outside? in most cases it's not

Comment: i am checking it.. is the way i am doing it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. in place on $servername trying giving the ip address of the server.
2. Determine if the server is accessible by sending a ping request
   like `ping serverip` Example `ping 192.168.100.12`

Try this too ..

```
    try {
    $hostname = "host";            //host
    $dbname = "dbname";            //db name
    $username = "user";            // username like 'sa'
    $pw = "pass";                // password for the user

    $dbh = new PDO ("mssql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
    }
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
    }
    unset($dbh); unset($stmt);
```

You can find more examples over here http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php

Comment: When I use your code the following error appears :
*Failed to get DB handle: could not find driver*
Which driver is it talking about

Comment: What server are you using ? whats the version ?

Comment: Server at hostedresourse.com  MSSQL 2008

Comment: Then you should use mssql driver you can get it from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx 
your using an old version of the driver\

Comment: These are the same drivers that i have installed they provide with the dll's i have mentioned in the question

Comment: did you try to ping the server ? is it reachable and did you also try specifying the port no with the IP address ?

Comment: Try reading through this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlexpress/thread/b5a846cc-2f60-4579-826c-b6d4243fb2a3

Answer (score 0):

$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$serverName;Database=*****",   "***DBNAME***", "***PWD***");
 Instead of DB name , here username should come